How can I merge STEP files using Open CASCADE while preserving the hierarchy and all associated information?
I don't know how to load multiple STEP files with Open CASCADE, merge them into a new STEP file while positioning them using x, y, z coordinates, and then export the result as a STEP file. Can someone help me with this?
It would be great if someone could provide an example code for this.
